# How can I change the shipping rate basing on what the cart contains?

Tags: commerce

I have configured my client's online vineyard store to display a flat rate up to £50 and free shipping thereafter.  However, they are now selling *Vineyard Tour* vouchers which are free to ship.

I am trying to set up a condition whereby:

- If the cart only contains a vineyard tour voucher or if the order is over £50 make the shipping rate free
- If the cart contains any other product (as well as a voucher) and is less than £50 standard shipping rate of £8.50.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the modules [Rules Bonus Pack](https://drupal.org/project/rb), [Conditional Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules_conditional), and [Commerce Rules Extra](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra) to create condition loops to compare a data value and set the shipping type in the actions.

```
Ex: 
Event = When calculating shipping

Condition = If cart contains item of type X

Action = add IF > Order total is greater than $50 > Add line-item: Free shipping

     add ELSE > Add line-item: Standard shipping
```